# Dynamically constructing bootstrap 4 modal link from inside Datatables.js plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm using Datatables.js jquery plugin to build html tables (jquery version 3.2.1); The html table that is being generated by datatables also needs to have one of the column cells (author_id) to be a clickable link that opens a bootstrap 4 modal, and passes the unique id of the author_id to the modal.

I'm able to (kinda) generate the href tag with all the attributes and am able to open the modal but for some reason the id's (author_id) that are being generated inside my DataTable initialization function are being displayed multiple times when I do a console.log (I put a comment before console.log in caps, to indicate where the multiples are being generated). Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Following is the code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://sonosfarm.com/prod/authors.cfc?method=Authors",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        if(response.length != 0){
            $("#authorsHiddenVar").val("");
            $("#authorsHiddenVar").val(JSON.stringify(response));
            $("#Authors").DataTable({
                data: response,
                columns:[
                    {
                        data: 'author_id',
                        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                            if(type== 'display'){
                               data = '<a  data-toggle="modal" data-
  target="#mymodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" 
    href="#mymodal" data-id=' + data + '>' + data + '</a>';
                            }

                        //THIS IS WHERE THE SAME UNIQUE author_id IS BEING 
                       //SHOWN MULTIPLE TIMES!
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'joined_date' 
                    },
                    {data: 'country'}
                ],
                responsive: true,
                order: [1, 'desc']
            });

        }
        else{
            console.log("There was no response from server!");
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("An Ajax server error was returned");
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
   });

});
```

The second issue I'm having is parsing the href tag inside the mymodal bootstrap modal - I tried the following code but I get undefined (when I try to retrieve the value of data-id:

```
   var mypostid = $("#mymodal").data('id');
   console.log( mypostid );
   //GETTING ERROR HERE
```

How do I retrieve the data-id (which is unique author_id) that is being passed to modal, and show various input fields based on the data-id?

Comment: If you're seeing the unique id multiple times in the console.log inside the render function, it suggests your data has the unique id multiple times.  Have you tried console.log outside the render function, like right after `if(response.length != 0){` ?  Also, can you provide a sample data set that demonstrates this problem ?

Comment: Also, it looks like your link has the `data-id` attribute.  Where is the `#mymodel` element, and how does it acquire the `data-id` ?

Comment: @devlin carnate - Yes I did a console.log right after if(response.length != 0), and the right number of id's are being displayed (with no multiples); the generated html table also displays the right number of id's without any multiples. When I was constructing the href link WITHOUT adding any of the bootstrap 4 specific pararms (data-toggle,data-id etc), the console.log was displaying the correct number of id's - it was when I added those params that things went haywire.

Comment: Yes, I found that one of the SO pages where the data-id was being used to pass a parameter to the bootstrap modal. The #mymodal element is inside of a html page (parent page) that contains all the bootstrap modal content. The modal part works fine - I'm able to generate a modal with all it's content. When I click on the <a href> link that is being constructed INSIDE the $("#Authors").DataTable initialization function, I need to be able to retrieve that value (author_id, which is unique) from inside the modal, in order to display various html elements.

Comment: I've found a partial solution - the way I was constructing the href tag was the problem - I found this solution that works and when I console.log, I get the right number of unique id's without any multiples  - 
     "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                                var createdlink = "<a href='rqstid:"+oData.author_id+"'>"+oData.author_id+"</a>";
                                $(nTd).html(createdlink);
                                console.log( createdlink);
                            }

Comment: Yeah, I was writing an answer that pointed that out.  In order to answer the other part of your question, we need to see how the modal is loaded.  When you click on the link, how does `#mymodal` get triggered to appear?

Comment: OK I've got the full link working like so: var createdlink = '<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#mymodal?action=update&author_id=' + oData.author_id+ '"' + '>' + oData.author_id + "</a>";  The bootstrap 4 modal is now initialized when I click the link; BUT i'm not sure how to retrieve the value of the action & author_id attributes in order to display the related fields in the modal. will update

Comment: The modal content is inside the same html page that the datatable is being displayed - authors.html - I have the modal code inside the html page like so:  <div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content"><!-- Modal Content -->  <div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Author list</h4></div><!--- Modal body --><div class="modal-body"></div></div></div> So this modal html code works, and I'm able to open the modal window upon clicking the link that is constructed inside the datatables func - I need to parse the href now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're missing quotes around the `data-id` value (i.e.  the HTML will render as data-id=something rather than data-id="something").

So, your datatable init would look like:

```
 $("#Authors").DataTable({
    data: response,
    columns:[
        {
            data: 'author_id',
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                if(type== 'display'){
                   return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#mymodal" data-id="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'joined_date' 
        },
        {data: 'country'}
    ],
    responsive: true,
    order: [1, 'desc']
});
```

Then, to get the author_id in your modal, you'll need to modify the jQuery that shows the modal.  You haven't provided that in your question, so I will give a generic example:

```
$('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var link = $(event.relatedTarget) // link that triggered the modal
  var author = link.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + author)
});
```

More on that from [Bootstrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#varying-modal-content).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Quick qn: what if i wanted to pass in an additional param called 'action=update' along w/ the author_id? Can I pass in multiple values in data-id attribute? thx for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple values via data attributes on your link.  But use data attributes (so `action=update` would be `data-action="update"`).  Then, in your jQuery, retrieve the value of the data attribute in the same way you're retrieving the author id.  `var action = link.data('action');`